# How to detect an iPhone connecting a network?

Tags: command-line-interface, iphone, packet-analyzer

I've noticed through watching Wireshark that when an iPhone connects to a wifi network, it sends out a few IGMP/MDNS packets to 224.0.0.251 (LAN broadcast, I think).  Is there any easy way to watch for these packets and then either run a script or send an event?

Or, is the best way to just run a packet sniffer?  Any simple ones that can send events or execute curl commands when a filter is triggered?

When I run nc -u -l 5353
I get:

```
My-Name-iPhonelocal???
                            x???)??
                                  ??cc^C
```

Can I do something like: 
nc -u -l 5353 | grep iPhonelocal | **execute command...**

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is not related to iPhone exclusively. According to RFC 3171, the IP 224.0.0.251 is used for Multicast DNS. The Multicast DNS feature of Bonjour technology allows devices on a local network to connect to each other by name without a separate DNS server.

If you want to detect particular devices on your network, you should use nmap and remote OS detection (OS-Fingerprinting) but that's not 100% accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that it was used by Bonjour.  I'm more looking for some Linux-fu to help me know how to trigger a response when something comes in from a pipe.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I'm basically trying to run a script as soon as my iPhone comes within range of my home network to turn a light on.  Any ideas?  Someone else had suggested using sed.

Comment: You could tie it into your DHCP server for your iPhone's IP/DHCP lease depending on your DHCP server/syslog config, etc.

Comment: tegbains suggestion sounds like a good one, use the MAC address of your iphone along with your DHCP server to trigger whatever you want to trigger

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> I'm basically trying to run a script as soon as my iPhone comes within range of my home network to turn a light on. Any ideas? Someone else had suggested using sed.

This sounds like a fun project!

You could do this by polling every 1 or 2 seconds with a ping.  It's a bit of a kludge, but the pings will cause negligible overhead.

1. Configure your DHCP server to always hand out the same IP to your iPhone (based on its MAC address)
2. Run a script on your linux computer that attempts to ping that IP every n seconds.
3. Turn your lights on/off based on some simple ping-response criteria

If you had a monitoring application like Zabbix, you could do this really easily.  You would set up a ping test for your iPhone, and create a trigger that runs an external script (to turn the light on/off).  Zabbix is overkill if this is *all* you're using it for, but you could come up with some other uses as well, I'm sure. :)

Also, in your script/trigger logic, you should make an attempt to avoid flicker.  The light should be switched on as soon as 1 ping gets a response.  It should only turn off after pings have gone unresponded for a full 5 minutes.  That way, your lights won't be flickering on and off when you have network congestion.

Comment: Thanks, I've written up my successes so far here: http://wecreategames.com/blog/?p=259  - I'll take a look at Zabbix and update my environment.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  This is all kinds of awesome!  You've inspired me to hack my house as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, OK, I'll bite.  Consider doing something like this (I'm being vague, as you'll have to tailor this to the tools you have available):

1. get your iPhone's MAC address
2. run a dhcpd daemon on your *nix box
3. ensure that said server is logging
4. write a [shell / perl / ruby / python] script to monitor that log file and take action on finding a line that matches that MAC address

Off hand, this sounds like an easier approach than attempting to interact with a sniffer in real time (however, maybe snort could be configured to do something like this).

I am, of course, making an assumption that the iPhone will attempt to renew its lease upon every connect.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

A while back I noticed that my firewall kept dropping packets like this, and logging the drops to kern.log.  Your post inspired me to whip up a little script to notify me when a certain iPhone connected to my wifi.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "ehlo" ]; then
    # If the script is ran, restart with the correct stdin
    tail -Fn 0 /var/log/kern.log | $(readlink -f $0) "ehlo"
    exit 0
fi

lasttime=0

while [ true ]; do
    read derp
    if [ $(echo "$derp" | fgrep -c "0m:ac:ad:dr:es:s0") -gt 0 ];then
        if [ $(($(date +%s)-$lasttime)) -ge 30 ];then
            lasttime=$(date +%s)
            # Pop up an ubuntu notification (requires libnotify-bin)
            notify-send "kern.log" "iPhone has appeared"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock

You might be able to setup knockd in someway to respond to the broadcast traffic.

I use port-knocking to protect SSH on some servers.  I am sure what you are trying to do isn't covered in any of the examples, but it might be possible.